# Is there any way to have different configurations for different databases in dbUnit / Arquillian Persistence extension?

Tags: jboss-arquillian, dbunit

I am trying to make integration tests that access the database using Arquillian Persistence Extension / DBunit.
It works well and I have this configured to test the part of the system that access MySQL:

```
<extension qualifier="persistence-dbunit">
        <property name="qualifiedTableNames">true</property>
        <property name="escapePattern">`?`</property>
    </extension>
```

The escapePattern is important because I have tables with names like "user", "key" and so on.

Now I want to test the part of the system that access Vertica. Vertica has a different escape character (") and does not recognize ` as escape. Every time I try to run the test, I get an error due to the ``.

Is there any way to have two different configurations which are activated depending on which test is ran? (Or which database connection is used)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limitation of APE (Arquillian Persistence Extension) at the moment is that it cannot control more than one database from within a single test. I understand that your case is different, you would like to run different suites of tests against different databases (or even the same tests against different databases but with different configuration). I solved it for APE using maven profiles and I test the code base against several different combinations of containers and databases (there is docker involved in-between which you will see in the referenced example, but that's not really important for this). My approach simply boils to following:

- I have separated `test-resource` folders for every configuration
- In there I have dedicated `arquillian.xml` configs relevant for given DB
- Maven profiles and adding those special `test-resource` folders on demand

This way I keep the tests portable, but I can shuffle some things around transparently.

I hope this will help you. Have a look at the config [here](https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-extension-persistence/blob/master/int-tests/pom.xml#L223-L266).